# WebService Provider trust worthiness in absence of UDDI registry (RESTful webservices or old ones)

Tags: web-services, security, soa, restful-architecture, uddi

I am new to WebServices and RESTful web services.

QUESTION: How can one quickly discover trust worthy web-service providers in absence of UDDI registry? I am asking from a network/systems/soa security-reliability perspective.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a web service marketplace which does not exist.

Comment: BTW, I don't recall that UDDI had much to do with trust. Especially since UDDI didn't catch on.

Comment: UDDIv3 has digital signatures, so there's your trust worthiness.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from UDDI, there's a few other options for web service discovery. The "trustworthiness" of the search results depends on your definition of the word.

For proving that the search results weren't modified in transit and proof of origin, you can use digital signatures.

- [WS-Discovery] http://specs.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/ws-discovery.pdf is a UDP multicast based xml/soap solution that can probably be digitally signed.
- [UPnP] is also udp multicast based xml/soap and may be signable
- Multicast DNS
- Roll your own solution

All of these assume you're on the same network, so there's a certain level of "trust" associated with that, assuming a certain level of network boundary security.

Other's have had luck using non http transports for all their transactions, such as OMG DDS, jGroups, or 0MQ. All of which support a certain degree of a peer authentication and/or encryption and are basically mutlicast based solutions (which usually don't go through firewalls). Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer. It is very informative.

Comment: Securing of communication channels was not my question. I am asking from an organizational perspective. How can one organization make sure that its servers connect to (business partner or trust worthy) service providers when there is no listing (collection or directory) like UDDI directory service? Is it not a bigger problem with REST style web services then in old style web service providers?